# What is the difference between IBM quantum simulator and others

Tags: ibm-q-experience, simulation

I am currently doing my final year undegraduate research. For many quantum inspired algorithms are simulated on Matlab. However if I am to run the algorithms on a Quantum Simulator provided by IBM, will that carry any significant importance.

Basically what makes IBM Quantum simulator stand out from general Matlab based or other simulators which generates random numbers for qubits.

Comment: Which MatLab simulator do you use? I also programmed one and I assumed no noise, i.e. the simulator returns theoretical results. However, IBM Q simulator incorporate some noise to the simulation which renders it closer to real quantum hardware where the noise is present always.

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit simulator supports advanced features like noise simulation. You can explore them by taking a look at the notebooks in https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/tree/master/qiskit/advanced/aer. In addition it is written in multi-threaded C++ and is optimized for high performance.